# Kaltura 10X Categories Index

Tags: kaltura

Category index in Kaltura is defined under partnerSortValue parameter.
In Kaltura 9X, this parameter is 0 for a new category and is updated only when moving category in the KMC (changing category order in the categories tree).
When deleting category, partnerSortValue does not change for other categories (in the same sub tree of course)

Is it different for Kaltura 10X, or does the Kaltura manage the partnerSortValue value for creating/moving/deleting categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked this issue on a newly installed Kaltura Server and the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`partnerSortValue` is a numeric field used by external applications to sort categories using the category.list API with parameter `filter.orderBy = +partnerSortValue`

http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/?object=KalturaCategoryOrderBy

So this field should not be modified internally in the API.

Comment: Yes, but my question was is in Kaltura v10X this field is modified when adding or removing category. Because in Kaltura 9X this field doesn't change, when for example remove category from list, other categories partnerSortValue stays the same